# Condição em Select - SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, select, h2database

Possuo uma tabela onde ficam armazenadas as prioridades de saída dos suprimentos por cliente, por exemplo:

```
cliente | codigosuprimento | prioridade | quantidaestoque
    1   |        500       |      1     |        20
    1   |        501       |      2     |        10
    1   |        502       |      3     |        00
    1   |        503       |      4     |        15
```

Nesse Caso eu deveria ter como retorno apenas a prioridade `1` e `4`. Ou seja quando houver itens para a prioridade 01 no estoque ela retorna caso não haja a prioridade 02 dever ser retornada. Os dados já são armazenados como pares no banco, ou seja, preciso olhar sempre para a prioridade 1 e 2, depois prioridade 3 e 4, minha questão é eu consigo em um comando de select já realizar esse filtro de trazer a **prioridade 02** apenas se a **prioridade 01** estiver zerada no estoque, trazer a **prioridade 04** somente se a **prioridade 03** estiver zerada no estoque e assim sucessivamente?

Hoje minha `Query` esta assim:

```
SELECT s
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora= :codigoModeloImpressora and 
s.codigoEmpresa= :codigoEmpresa
ORDER BY s.prioridadeSaida, s.suprimento
```

Porém preciso alterar para que se adapte a necessidade citada acima.

Estrutura tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: Oracle Database, SQL Server, MariaDB, PostgreSQL ...?

Comment: Onde está a coluna que informa a quantidade que deve ser enviada para o cliente? Isto é, e se a quantidade solicitada pelo cliente for maior do que o que há em estoque?

Comment: @JoséDiz é H2 o banco de dados, é essa questão da quantidade solicitada não interfere pro que eu preciso

Comment: Tentou com um subselect e NOT EXISTS !?

Comment: @Motta poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: Publica a estrutura real da tabela e suas chaves como disse o @José Diz

Comment: @Motta alterei a pegunta com a estrutura da tabela

Comment: Procure aqui http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#case_when na documentação na base de dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Santos,

Acredito que a solução para seu problema seja o uso de `NOT EXISTS`, em cada query e union de todas.

**NOT EXISTS**

NOT EXISTS funciona como EXISTS, exceto pela cláusula WHERE em que é usado para ser atendido se nenhuma linha for retornada pela subconsulta.
Por exemplo, para localizar os nomes de produtos que não estão na subcategoria rodas:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Production.ProductSubcategory
     WHERE ProductSubcategoryID = 
            Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
        AND Name = 'Wheels')
```

Ou seja o `not exists` normalmente vem acompanhado de uma validação em outra tabela. No caso do exemplo ele não trará caso tenha uma subcategoria com o nome name.

fonte: https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx

**Exemplo**

Abstraindo seu problema, para conseguir mostrar a solução

```
SELECT s
  FROM SuprimentosPedidos s
 WHERE s.Prioridade = 4 AND
       NOT EXISTS(
SELECT s
      FROM SuprimentosPedidos s
     WHERE s.Prioridade = 3
)
```

E fazer isso nas demais seleções.